# button not going to correct links

Tags: reactjs, json

I am using react and doing my portfolio

when people click on the button to view my github repo or project it goes to the wrong place

```
const Project = () => {
  return (
    <div className='work-container'>
      <h1 className='project-heading'>Projects</h1>
      <div className='project-container'>
        {ProjectData.map((val, ind) => {
          return (
            <ProjectCard
              key={ind}
              imagesource={val.imagesource}
              title={val.title}
              text={val.text}
              view={val.view}
              github={val.github}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this is what my data file contains

```
const ProjectData = [
  {
    imagesource: project1,
    title: 'Diamond Devs Tech Blog',
    text: 'A community of developers who can write blogs about code or ask questions Built out of a need for developers have a nice simple platform rather than the complex ones out there in the marketplace, this was for an assignment foor my Bootcamp was challenging as had to do the front and backend from scratch using tech that I am still getting used too.',
    view: 'https://diamond-developers-tech-blog.herokuapp.com/',
    github: 'https://github.com/breakfireaus/diamond-developers-tech-blog',
  },
 
]

export default ProjectData
```

I tried the above and instead of going to view project or github it goes to for example

https://matthew-younger-portfolio.herokuapp.com/portfolio/https://diamond-developers-tech-blog.herokuapp.com/

instead of just

https://diamond-developers-tech-blog.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You need to show `<ProjectCard />` code.

Comment: the card is showing but the links are not working @kyun

Comment: I mean the code about `<ProjectCard />` component.

Comment: sorry, but the component is showing , i am trying to get the links when you click on the button to work, @kyun  the portfolio is deployed at just click on view or github on one of the projects and you will understand more on my issue, https://matthew-younger-portfolio.herokuapp.com/portfolio

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed code from you github repo. What you are doing is using React router NavLink to move to an external website which you cannot do as you can use it move within your application [Documentation](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html)
.

You can convert them to a tag in your Project Card and they will work fine. You can use target="_blank" if you want to open the link in new tab.

```
import "./ProjectCardStyle.css";
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const ProjectCard = (props) => {


  return (
    <div className="project-card">
      <img src={props.imagesource} alt="Project Imagery" />
      <h2 className="project-title">{props.title}</h2>
      <div className="project-details">
        <p>{props.text}</p>
        <div className="project-buttons">
          <a target={"_blank"} href={props.view} className="btn">
            VIEW
          </a>
          <a target={"_blank"} href={props.github} className="btn">
            Github
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectCard;
```